# Cadquery objects are created but not displayed in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, cad

Just got started with Jupyter-cadquery==2.0.0 using my new conda environment on my windows machine. Installed all the modules following these [links](https://github.com/bernhard-42/jupyter-cadquery/find/master) for [installation](https://github.com/bernhard-42/jupyter-cadquery#installation):

[and this one to set up a running environment](https://medium.com/@nrk25693/how-to-add-your-conda-environment-to-your-jupyter-notebook-in-just-4-steps-abeab8b8d084) so Jupyter works.

All is well in Jupyter Notebook. Was able to successfully execute Cadquery example code and generate the correct output.

However, when I run the very same notebook in Jupyter lab (also launched from the same conda env) I do not get output. I even enabled and rebuilt the Jupyter lab session after installing the jupyter_cadquery extension, but no output... What should I do to enable the output as is shown in the example documentation?

** Apologies if my images are not visible. Stackoverflow doesnt allow me to upload images

The output of my jupyter lab code is as follows:

HBox(children=(VBox(children=(HBox(children=(Checkbox(value=False, description='Axes', indent=False, _dom_clas…
IntProgress(value=0, layout=Layout(width='95%'), max=4)
<jupyter_cadquery.cad_display.CadqueryDisplay at 0x20dfbae38b0>

[Jupyter notebook output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyyPM.jpg)
[Jupyter lab output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPZu6.jpg)